# \leavevmode and list in theorem

Tags: theorems

As we know, the *\leavevmode* command forces TeX or LaTeX to exit vertical mode. However, I don't really know why in the instruction:

```
\begin{theorem} \leavevmode \begin{enumerate}
      \item ............
      \item ............
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

causes the first *\item* to be written on the next line; that is, why does LaTeX break the line with that command?

If I don't type *\leavevmode* the first *\item* is displayed on the same line as the word **Theorem**.

Also, could someone tell me why to keep the first *\item* on the same line by default. Outside the environment, the lists start on another line.

Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate} \item a \item b \end{enumerate}
\item c
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

you get the expected

[image]

This means that your last statement is not quite accurate: `enumerate` doesn't go to a new line if nothing is between it and a preceding `\item`.

You don't want the inner `enumerate` to start on the next line, do you? Well, if you *really* want, add `\mbox{}` before the inner `\begin{enumerate}` and you get

[image]

The `theorem` environment defined with `\newtheorem` is actually a `trivlist`, the basic environment on which all lists are built on. So, the reason why the first item in your `enumerate` is typeset at the same level as “Theorem” is the same as the situation above.

If you add `\mbox{}`, then the implicit `\item` at the end of the code for `\theorem` will start the item and the following `enumerate` will go to the next line.

Is `\mbox{}` better than `\leavevmode`? Yes, in my opinion. Because `\mbox{}` is documented in the official manual, whereas `\leavevmode` isn't. It's a handy tool for “programming”, but shouldn't appear in the document body. But that's just my opinion.

I have another opinion: a statement of a theorem should never start with a list. Add some words before the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have understood everything. However, you could tell me why \leavevmode behaves similarly in this case to \mbox{}.

Comment: @GermánGarcíaLópez The definition of `\mbox` is `\leavevmode\hbox`. ;-)